# Extracting first value of a cluster of values in a column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem:** Running through a column to extract all the first cells in a cluster of cells that have the same value, however the trick is that even if a value is seen previously in the column and occurs again later in the column (perhaps in another cluster), but not in the following cell it will be considered a 'unique' value and be extracted again:

E.g. Probably makes more sense with the following example:

**Data:**

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 012 | 1 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 234 | 2 |
| 345 | 2 |
| 456 | 2 |
| 567 | 1 |
| 678 | 1 |
| 789 | 3 |
| 890 | 3 |

**Output needed:**

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 012 | 1 |
| 234 | 2 |
| 567 | 1 |
| 789 | 3 |

Comment: What did you try by your own?

Comment: What is your cluster definition, in this context? Only changing the value in the column B:B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. I (only) hope I correctly understood your definition for a "cluster" in this context:

```
Sub extractFirstClaster()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, arrCl
  Dim i As Long, k As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastR).value
  ReDim arrFin(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(arr))
  ReDim arrCl(UBound(arr) - 1)
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr) - 1
        If arr(i, 2) = arr(i + 1, 2) Then
            If IsError(Application.match(arr(i, 2), arrCl, 0)) Then
                k = k + 1
                arrFin(1, k) = CStr(arr(i, 1))
                arrFin(2, k) = arr(i, 2)
                arrCl(k - 1) = arr(i, 2)            
            End If
        Else
            ReDim arrCl(UBound(arr) - 1)
        End If
  Next i

  ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To 2, 1 To k)
  With sh.Range("D2").Resize(k, 2)
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrFin)
  End With
End Sub
```

Please, learn that when you ask a question it is **mandatory** to prove that you did something to solve it by your onw and you also must frequently check if there are clarification questions and answer them...

I made an exception, supposing that you do not know the rules, but only now.

Please, send some feedback after testing the code.

Comment: @smitthy: Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: Cheers, FaneDuru, worked nicely for me! Also, apologies since its my first time asking - previously tried unique() and lookup arrays, but realized it didn't suit my requirement.

Comment: @smitthy:  Glad I could help! But, even if your tried solution did not work as you need it, you should post your code. It is necessary to prove that you did something, even if you couldn't find an appropriate code to do what you need...